# Fabric REST API fails to bring up the API for the newly added organization

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am using [Altoros - Fabric Rest](https://github.com/Altoros/fabric-rest) to have API to Fabric network. When I am trying to add a new organization like [Adding an ORG to a channel](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/channel_update_tutorial.html), I am getting an error while bringing up the docker compose file of the new organization.

The REST API works fine for the organizations that already present in network.
I checked the log, this what the error is.

```
_connect - timed out after:5000

api.ORG3.example.com         | [2018-04-26 13:02:22.491] [ERROR] peer-listener - (((((((((((( Got block error )))))))))))

api.ORG3.example.com         | [2018-04-26 13:02:22.492] [ERROR] peer-listener - Error: Unable to connect to the peer event hub
```

Not able to get anything, looked into Fabric sdk of Event Hub also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked after restarting the API server after the new organization addition.Full answer here [Fabric Altoros](https://github.com/Altoros/fabric-rest/issues/1).